# Is it ok to duplicate a program memory to avoid inline reset?

Tags: c, memory, state

I have a time-critical function that needs to be executed multiple times sequentially.

```
void task(state_t *state);
```

It uses a relatively large amount of memory, so I figured that allocating it  once at the beginning, and freeing it at the end would speed up the task sequence.

```
state_t *state = alloc_state();

task(state);
task(state);
task(state);

free_state(state);
```

But the memory has to be reset (all memory set to 0) between tasks, which is as slow as allocating it. Since memory usage is not critical, I figured that I could duplicate the program state, and use a thread to reset one when the other is in use.

```
state_t *state_a = alloc_state();
state_t *state_b = alloc_state();
pthread_t thread1, thread2;

while (1) {

  /* running task on state_a */
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, task,        (void*) state_a);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, reset_state, (void*) state_b);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

  /* running task on state_b */
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, task,        (void*) state_b);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, reset_state, (void*) state_a);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}

free_state(state_a);
free_state(state_b);
```

It works well, but I find it inelegant. Is it ok to do this? Is there a more elegant solution? Also, even if memory is not critical, is there a solution without the time-memory trade-off?

Comment: Consider using a thread pool, creating a thread isn't exactly cheap.

Comment: `But the memory has to be reset between tasks, which is as slow as allocating it.` If resetting and allocating is roughly the same cost, why not just initialise and free memory in separate thread instead of resetting two states? Or to run each tasks in their own threads, sequencing only the actual run, but leaving setup and teardown of the state parallel. That won't be cheaper, but it won't be inelegant.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it ok to do this?

Yes, deferring time non-critical work to background processes is a time honoured trade off between getting the essential piece of work done, and completing the whole task (cleanup included).

> But the memory has to be reset between tasks, which is as slow as allocating it.

The only time memory must be completely reset is when handing it to an untrusted process. It is a security concern to prevent secrets from being communicated between insecure processes, or between secure and insecure processes.

An algorithm can always be tailored to initialise, or reinitialise the data structures as it operates and only as much as is needed to express the correct state. Most of this cost will need to be paid anyway as the algorithm must set the state anyway.

As for non-memory resources such as file handles, sockets, device handles, etc... you will need to handle those a little differently. Usually it hurts performance and opportunity to leave those open indefinitely, but they are also slower to de-allocate. The solution you suggested before `using a background worker to manage their cleanup` is a good compromise here.

> Is there a more elegant solution?

That does depend on what you mean by elegance.

As with an management issue there is a measure of book keeping needed to maintain state. Each solution trades off against properties like:

- how much book keeping
- when the book keeping is done
- who is responsible for the book keeping
- how invasive the book keeping is

Solutions:

1. Special well-crafted algorithm/system. You simply cannot get more elegant than this. For many problems it is still a black box on how to attain a well-crafted algorithm/system for a specific problem, but you will know it when you use it.
2. Garbage Collection. This is hard to write and get correct. Best to use the language offering, or a battle-hardened third-party offering. As a side benefit memory allocation is (usually) fast. On the other-hand there is no guarantee on how much memory will be used, how quickly it will be cleaned up, and when/how the overheads manifest.
3. Memory Pool/Custom Memory allocator/deallocator. If you know the specific memory structures that will be used by your algorithm, a custom memory manager can greatly accelerate memory allocation/deallocation. If you know one thread will use it at a time, it can be accelerated even more. It also helps constrain the total memory inflight, and helps to co-locate memory in use by the algorithm.
4. [Quiescent State](https://preshing.com/20160726/using-quiescent-states-to-reclaim-memory/). Best if you need to share data between concurrent processes, but still ensure it is sanitised. It is another form of Garbage collector, but one that can be specialised and hence optimised for specific work-loads, between specific workers without affecting or being affected by the greater system.
5. Message passing. This is essential your solution. The main algorithm treats used memory as a by product that is sent as a message on a queue to a recycler. The recycler treats the memory and either sends it back for reuse or deallocates it. If the main algorithm has not received sanitised memory, it will allocate more.

**Good Practice**

As with any sort of resource Management concern I would go for a generic offering/technique that is battle hardened and relatively non-intrusive. Resist the urge to optimise early.

If the generic offering isn't solving the issue, first get some actual profiling on your code. It is surprising how often other code is responsible. Should the resource managing code actually be the culprit, often a little tuning of the configuration will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> It works well, but I find it inelegant. Is it ok to do this?

Yes, this is ok.

> Is there a more elegant solution? Also, even if memory is not critical, is there a solution without the time-memory trade-off?

Algorithms can be made to initialize their own data, and thus do not require the memory to be reset.  So, the idea would be to transform your algorithms so they have this property.

For example, garbage collectors need to identify live objects vs. dead objects.  So, one approach is to mark all objects as dead, then trace every reachable object from some set of roots (like global variables and stack variables).  If they reach an object thought of as dead, they change its mark to live (and if they reach a live object, they need trace no further down that path).  In the end all visited objects are marked live and any objects still marked dead are garbage.  However, the initial phase of marking all objects as live is costly, so rather than doing that, they reverse the sense of true & false for live vs. dead at every collection.  Since the dead objects are all collected, when the collection is finished, all objects are marked live.  So, that value for live is used as the initial value for dead in the next collection.  In one collection the live/dead bit in the object is true for live, and in the next, it is false means live.  Thus, the costly initialization step can be skipped.

Many other algorithms and approaches positively initialize the memory they use; these don't require an initialization phase.

Some keep track of free memory vs. used memory, using a size counter, index, or a pointer.  They know that memory beyond a certain range has not been initialized.  A file system keeps track of how large each file is and prevents us from reading past the end-of-file.  Because of that, it does not have to initialize disc blocks (i.e. to zero) when allocating a free block for an expanding file — the contents of that block will be initialized with file data by the application writing the file, so, no separate initialization step is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a copy-on-write memory. The easiest way to get this is by fork()-ing a separate process, run your task in the child process, have the parent wait for child completion, and when you're done, terminate and the parent will resume to fork() for the next task. If you need to share state between tasks, you can setup a shared memory or transfer the shared state through pipes.

There is also a way to have [copy-on-write behaviour without fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998943/get-the-copy-on-write-behaviour-of-forking-without-fork), though this might be a bit tricky to get right.

---

Alternate approach you can take, though this will be task dependant, is that you restructure your state data structure so that you don't have to modify existing data when modifying the state. Instead, any modifications should be done by appending a description of the change to the base state. This is the basic idea of MVCC (multi version concurrency control). This way, resetting state is simply done by creating new version of the state, and you can free the memory whenever.

Comment: If OP's deadlines aren't being met allocating new memory, odds are good the overhead of a fork isn't going to be acceptable, either.